# How to declare array variables of types: Double/Cell

Tags: matlab

I have got 2 variables
`A of value  <240x500 double>` and
`B of value <1x500 cell>`

How can I declare another 2 variables
`C of type A` and
`D of type B`   ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to define variable types in Matlab. To declare `C` and `D`, simply do the following:

```
C = zeros(240,500);
D = cell(1,500);
```

This will create new matrices of the same sizes of `A` and `B`. `C` will be filled with `0`'s and `D` will be an empty cell matrix. If you would prefer the new matrices to be initialized to some other value, you could do use the `ones()` function instead:

```
x = 100;
C = ones(240,500) * 100;
```

This will populate the `C` matrix with `100`'s

Comment: I need the cell variable. Other wise I'm getting an error "Conversion to double from cell is not possible."

Comment: Sorry, I missed seeing that `B` was a cell matrix. Updated my answer.